# How to change the location of chrome's cookie?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, cookies

I want to put the cookie location on my D drive, because my C drive is too heavy now. but my chrome is on C drive. i just wonder if there anyway to minimize the size of the chrome in C drive instead of reinstall the whole chrome in D drive.

Comment: I added an answer below be I wanted to mention, it's likely other Chrome cache files and such consuming much more space than cookies specifically so the solution I provided will help gain more disk partition space back to the core "C" drive than just the Chrome cookies folders or whatever so this solution is for the entire Chrome AppData directory, etc. for the logged on profile you run this as.

Answer (score 1):

### Move Chrome User AppData Folder to another Drive Location

You can use [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) with applicable parameters to copy over the `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome` directory to the new drive location where you want the **Chrome** files to exist, delete the original `~\Chrome` folder, and then use [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to create a directory symbolic link to the location on the other disk drive partition.

### Batch Script

> **Note:** *Be sure to right-click and select `run as administrator` when you run this script. Also, set the value in the `Dest=` variable
>   to be the new full path and folder name you want the Chrome user
>   profile `/appdata` directory to reside on the other drive location but
>   make this be a folder like `D:\Chrome` or something meaningful and not
>   the root of the drive like `D:\`. Just save below logic to a text file and rename to  `<something>.cmd` and right-click to **run as administrator**.*

```
@ECHO ON

SET Src=C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome
SET Dest=D:\Chrome
TASKKILL /F /IM "chrome.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%Dest%" MD "%Dest%"
SET FName=*.*

SET OPT=/PURGE /S /ZB /SEC /COPYALL /SECFIX /R:5 /W:5 /TS /FP
SET CMD=robocopy "%Src%" %FName% "%Dest%" %OPT%
%CMD%
IF EXIST "%Src%" RD /S /Q "%Src%"
MKLINK /D "%Src%" "%Dest%"
PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [TaskKill](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)
- [Robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)
- [RD](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)
- [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)
- **`mklink /?`**

  > ```
  > Creates a symbolic link.
  >
  > MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
  >
  >         /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
  >                 symbolic link.
  >         /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
  >         /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
  >         Link    Specifies the new symbolic link name.
  >         Target  Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
  >                 refers to.
  > ```